# Proving that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\frac{x}{\epsilon}\bigg)=\delta (x)$

Tags: distribution-theory

> Prove that  $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{1}{\pi
> x}\sin\frac{x}{\epsilon}\bigg)=\delta (x)$$

My attempt:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\frac{x}{\epsilon}\bigg)=\delta (x)$$

Re-write LHS to:
$$\bigg(\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\frac{x}{\epsilon}\bigg)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}-\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)$$

Let us integrate both sides,
$$\int\bigg[\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}-\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\bigg]\text{d}x=\int \delta(x)\text{d}x$$

$$\int\bigg[\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}-\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\bigg]\text{d}x=\theta(x) +C$$

Take the limit:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\bigg[\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}-\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\bigg]\text{d}x=\theta(x) +C$$

$$\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg[ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\bigg(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\text{d}x-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\text{d}x\bigg]=\theta(x) +C$$

where we obtain:

$$\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg[ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{Erf}\bigg(-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}\bigg)+C-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{Erf}\bigg(\frac{ix}{\epsilon}\bigg)+C\bigg]=\theta(x) +C$$

Re-write:

$$\frac{Ci}{\pi}\bigg[ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{Erf}\bigg(-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}\bigg)-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\text{Erf}\bigg(\frac{ix}{\epsilon}\bigg)\bigg]=\theta(x) +C$$

Now we can solve the problem by letting $\epsilon=0$ and obtain

$$0=\theta(x) +C$$

which gives, with $\theta(x)=-C$

Insert now in the RHS of

$$\frac{i}{2\pi}\bigg[ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\bigg(\frac{e^{-\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\text{d}x-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{\epsilon}}}{x}\bigg)\text{d}x\bigg]=-C +C$$
and obtain:

$$0=0$$

But this seems like an odd result. I wonder if the entire approach is wrong.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

PS: I found this in a paper, but am not sure it can be used:

[image]

Comment: Proof has to show $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \ \delta_\epsilon(f) = f(0)$. I

ts easier to Fourier transform. Easy to show,  the $\sin x /x =\text{sinc} x$ function has a unit square well step function as fourier transform. 

The evaluation integral with test functions in $S$  is converted to a convolution over an interval. 

Proof by pointwise convergence of functions to a distribution is a special art of analysis.

Comment: How would that look more or less like? Do a Fourier transform of both sides then take the limit? Have a  look at the PS part I just added. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $f(x)\in{\cal D}(\mathbb{R})$ that is the space of the test functions, one can see that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)f(x)=f(0),
$$
given the proper change of variable $y=\frac{x}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 1):

We start with the following,
\begin{align}
I &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{\pi x}\sin(\frac{x}{\epsilon})\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{i}{2\pi x} \left(e^{-i(\frac{x}{\epsilon})}-e^{i(\frac{x}{\epsilon})}\right)
\end{align}
Then let $u=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$,
\begin{align}
&=\lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} \frac{i}{2\pi x} \left(e^{-iux}-e^{iux}\right) \\
&=  \frac{i}{2\pi x}\left[e^{-iux}\right]_{u=-\infty}^\infty \\
&=\frac{i}{2\pi x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty -ix e^{-iux} du\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iux}du
\end{align}
Now we use the integral representation of the $\delta$ function to find,
\begin{align}
I&=\delta(x)
\end{align}